# Creating Individual Rows with based on a cell value in a column

Tags: python, database, excel, csv

I am looking to take a CSV file and sort the file using python 2.7 to get an individual value based on two columns for a block and lot.  My data looks like now in the link below:

[Beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ahKG.jpg)

I want to be able on the lot value to create extra lines using Python to automate this into a new CSV where the values will look like this when drawn out on the new CSV

[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45tiB.jpg)

So I know that I need read the row and the column and based on the cell value for the lot column if there is a "," then the row will be copied to the next row in the other csv and all the values before the first column will be copied only and then the second, third etc.

After the Commas are separated out, then the ranges will be managed in a similar way in a third CSV.  If there is a single value, the whole row will be copied as is.

Thank you for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

1. On Windows open files in binary mode or else you get double new lines.
2. I assumed rows are separated by `;` because cells contains `,`
3. First split by `,`, then check for ranges
4. `print line` is for debugging
5. Error checking is left as an exercise for the reader.

Code:

```
import csv

file_in = csv.reader(open('input.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';')
file_out = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=';')

for i, line in enumerate(file_in):
    if i == 0:
        # write header
        file_out.writerow(line)
        print line
        continue

    for j in line[1].split(','):
        if len(j.split('-')) > 1:
            # lines with -
            start = int(j.split('-')[0])
            end = int(j.split('-')[1])
            for k in xrange(start, end + 1):
                line[1] = k
                file_out.writerow(line)
                print line
        else:
            # lines with ,
            line[1] = j
            file_out.writerow(line)
            print line
```